# Detect complete.ly User Selection?

Tags: javascript, complete.ly

In using complete.ly, I'd like to catch the event where the user has selected an option from those presented.  See the example at http://complete-ly.appspot.com/examples/clauses.html.

I don't see any such event in the API.  I've also looked through the js and nothing jumps out.

The only event apparently available is fired at input string change character-by-character, which doesn't tell me when the user has made the selection.

(Intent here is to use the selection for some further AJAX processing.)

Again, how to catch the user-select event?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you deliberately listen to the dom object you can not do that.
However, as you pointed out you can be notified of user selections so at that stage you probably can fire your ajax calls